# How gather lists and load into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following code creates a dataframe, tokenizes, and filters stopwords. However, **am I stuck trying to properly gather the results to load back into a column of the dataframe**. Trying to put the results back into the dataframe (using commented code) produces the following error `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`. It seems like the issue is with how I'm loading the lists back into the df. I think it is treating them one at a time. I'm not clear how to form a list of lists, which is what I *think* is needed. Neither `append()` nor `extend()` seem appropriate, or if they are I'm not doing it properly. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

## Minimal example

```
# Load libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import spacy

# Create dataframe and tokenize
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text': ['This is the first text. It is two sentences',
                            'This is the second text, with one sentence']})
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
df['Tokens'] = ''
doc = df['Text']
doc = doc.apply(lambda x: nlp(x))
df['Tokens'] = doc
# df # check dataframe

# Filter stopwords
df['No Stop'] = ''
def test_loc(df):
    for i in df.index:
        doc = df.loc[i,'Tokens']
        tokens_no_stop = [token.text for token in doc if not token.is_stop]
        print(tokens_no_stop)
# df['No Stop'] = tokens_no_stop # THIS PRODUCES AN ERROR
test_loc(df)
```

## Result

```
['text', '.', 'sentences']
['second', 'text', ',', 'sentence']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you need a list of lists in order for the assignment to work.
Another solution can be to use [pandas.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) as you used in the beginning of your code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import spacy

df = pd.DataFrame({'Text': ['This is the first text. It is two sentences',
                            'This is the second text, with one sentence']})
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

df['Tokens'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda x: nlp(x))

def remove_stop_words(tokens):
    return [token.text for token in tokens if not token.is_stop]

df['No Stop'] = df['Tokens'].apply(remove_stop_words)
```

Notice you don't have to create the column before assigning to it.

Comment: This is **way better** than how I was doing it. Thank you so much. This is an elegant solution I believe I can generalize to a number of procedures. Again, thanks.